# Getting SSL Exception in App auth

Tags: android, google-oauth, appauth

I am getting the below error when trying to hit the App auth url. 
`E/AppAuth: Network error` when retrieving discovery document.

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found`.